# Why is the scale factor of a matrix the determinant squared?

Tags: matrices, determinant

For a matrix e.g
$$\begin{bmatrix}2\sqrt{3}  &-2\\2&2\sqrt{3} \end{bmatrix}$$
that is a rotation followed by an enlargement, why is the scale factor of the enlargement the  **root** of the determinant of this matrix?
I would have thought that it would be the determinant of the enlargement matrix once separated out.
Here the scale factor for the enlargement comes to $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant is the scaling factor of the *area*, so it makes sense that the square root of this is the scaling factor of the *length* of each vector, which is $4$ here.

Answer (score 1):

You know that your matrix $M$ has the form $\lambda R$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $R$ is a rotation. It follows that $\det R=1$ and 
$$
\det M = \det (\lambda R) = \lambda^2 \det R = \lambda^2
$$